# AngularJs Controller code running indefinitely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

so I'm setting up a website to use Angular Routing, but I'm getting really odd behaviour. When I visit a route, it seems to be running the code in the controller indefinitely until the tab crashes. Here is my routing:

```
angular.module(app.appName)
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'homeController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when('/MyWishlists', {
                    templateUrl: 'assets/html/areas/MyWishlists/myWishlists.html',
                    controller: 'myWishlistsController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when('/Login', {
                    templateUrl: 'assets/html/areas/login/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]);
```

And here is my `loginController`:

```
angular.module(app.appName)
    .controller('loginController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            console.log('login');
        }]);
```

When I visit `http://localhost:50925/Login` it will run that `console.log('login');` over and over until Chrome ends it. What am I doing here 
that's causing this, I've never seen it before?

Could it be to do with my concatenated file? I'm using gulp to combine all controllers into `controllers.js`.

Edit: I have also just tried creating a new controller, `homeController` and added it to my routes, and it doesn't use the `homeController` at all on either routes that it's defined.

```
angular.module(app.appName)
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'homeController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when('/Home', {
                    controller: 'homeController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when('/MyWishlists', {
                    templateUrl: 'assets/html/areas/MyWishlists/myWishlists.html',
                    controller: 'myWishlistsController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when('/Login', {
                    templateUrl: 'assets/html/areas/login/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginController',
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]);

angular.module('wishlist')
    .controller('homeController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            console.log('home');
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. The problem for me is that I'm using ASP.NET but I'm using a method that bypasses the MVC Pipeline entirely. In order to do this, I needed to create an Index.cshtml and tell the application to serve the file. At this point, however, it returns all files that aren't specifically listed in the web.config rewrite rules as HTML to the browser. I had allowed my assets/js folder through, but not my HTML, so instead of serving the HTML templates with Angular, it was retrieving the entire recompiled page as a response to the browser, which was in turn giving the browser a whole HTML page to render the new route, and it got stuck doing this over and over until the browser eventually ends it.

In short, to solve the problem, I had to add it to my rules in my web.config.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(wwwroot/.*|assets/min.*|assets/html.*|bower_components/.*|api/.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="AngularJS Wildcard" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cshtml" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: It make sense. I faced the same problem while developing a java spring mvc application. as web.xml reads and use spring url mapping first, the angular routing was hided by it.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject ngRoute while defining angular module. Here is the [Link](https://codingislove.com/angularjs-for-complete-beginners/) which will help you to define ngRoute and hope so it will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm sure I injected `ngRoute` into my module, but I'll check when I can.

Comment: I have injected `ngRoute` in my module, here: `angular.module(app.appName, [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource'
]);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function in your controller doest have a name and some errors are there. you can check that. You need to add something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Angularjs need to inject the module you want to use. All the dependency are required to inject before use.

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Hi, I've setup `app.appName` as a global var in a previous js file, if that's what you mean. This approach has worked in many other projects, but I'll try and explicitly define the module name in my controller.